# Having an exception when I connect bluetooth using socket in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making Android bluetooth application which can turn on or off bluetooth search devices paired devices and so on every thing works fine but the problem occur on connecting device when I click on `listview` item exception occurs:

> Java.lang.NullpointerException

How to overcome this situation?

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
       android:text="@string/Text" />

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/turnOn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/on" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/turnOff"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/off" />

   </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginTop="80dp" >

       <Button
          android:id="@+id/paired"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/List" />

       <Button
          android:id="@+id/search"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/Find" />

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/listView1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="200dp" >

       </ListView>

   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JavaCode

```
public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);//Exception
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }
```

LOGCAT

```
04-19 20:45:53.353  10902-10902/com.example.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
04-19 20:45:53.363  10902-10902/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.app.ConnectThread.<init>(ConnectThread.java:23)
            at com.example.app.MainActivity.connect(MainActivity.java:124)
            at com.example.app.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:30)
            at com.example.app.MainActivity$5.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:117)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
            at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3561)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 20:45:53.373      125-254/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.app/.MainActivity
04-19 20:45:53.873      125-140/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{407b6608 com.example.app/.MainActivity}
04-19 20:45:53.933      234-234/? I/CarouselTimeLog﹕ onStart() finish: 1429458353942
```

I am making bluetooth application and everything goes fine until I click on the `ListView`, having an exception at `tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);`

Comment: Can you show us MainActivity:124, where you create the ConnectThread object?

Comment: Yes,    private void connect() {
        ConnectThread con=new ConnectThread(device);
        con.run();
    }

Comment: myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                  connect();
              }
          });

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.app.ConnectThread.<init>(ConnectThread.java:23)
```

So the issue is here:

```
public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
    mmDevice = device;
    try {
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);//Exception
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    mmSocket = tmp;
}
```

On the line inside the try statement:

```
tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

So that means that `device` must be null. Which means you're passing in a null value to the constructor of `ConnectThread`. The issue will be where you're creating the BluetoothDevice object.

Comment: Well you haven't actually showed us the code with the error, so I can't give you a solution. I told you exactly where the error is though. Device is currently null, and it shouldn't be.